# Geometric measure theory on manifolds: suggested book

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, book-recommendation, geometric-measure-theory

I am a newcome to geometric measure theory, but I would like to learn it directly from the context of manifolds, without reference to an Euclidean ambient space. Do you recommend a book on this topic with this point of view?

Comment: I imagine you know the book by L. Santalo, and find it too "down to Earth" ?

Comment: You really can't do *anything* involving analysis and geometry on a manifold without first understanding how things work in Euclidean space, as the local structure is coming precisely from Euclidean space. Whether the manifold *sits* in a Euclidean space is really irrelevant. You've looked at Frank Morgan's introductory text? It provides an excellent conceptual overview without getting bogged down in technicalities (like the masterwork by Federer).

Comment: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540606567

Comment: @JeanMarie: Santalo's book is quite beautiful, but it's classical integral geometry and not at all GMT-ish. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, so suppose I already know how things work in the Euclidean setting. What books cover the topic in a manifold setting?

Comment: There's really nothing like what you want. For transferring the (co)area formula to manifolds, see 3.2.46 of Federer. For the regularity theory for minimizing currents, Nash embed your manifold and then proceed as in Leon Simon's book. He develops the regularity theory for currents with support in a smooth submanifold of $\Bbb R^N$. For the theory of varifolds  in Riemannian manifolds, see the book "Existence and regularity of minimal surfaces on Riemannian manifolds" by Pits.

Comment: For currents, see also "Cartesian currents in the calculus of variations" (especially the first volume) by Giaquanta, Modica, and Soucek.